# How to get data sent from 1 page to another?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two page - 
1. Index.html
                  2. Main.html

I want to sent a data from index to main. Which i can do like this:

```
<form action="Main.html" method="POST">
   <input type="text" name="q">
</form>
```

I want to display the data sent from Index.html on Main.html

I know two methods of doing it - 

1. using `method="GET"` in the form tag and get the data from the src(link).
2. Using side languages like php.

> I dont want to use the first method to do this thing.

Please someone give me the codes of php for doing this.

**It would be more help if you can tell any other way of doing this**

Comment: `using method="post" in the form tag` and `get the data from the src(link).` don't you think it's controversial?

Comment: May be you can check the option of sending data via query string parameter.

Comment: Change the form `method` to `GET`, then use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: @Rory McCrossan i dont want to use that thing

Comment: To get the data from the url, you would need `method="GET"`, not `method="POST"`. Please give this a try yourself before asking for code. Using PHP, you can grab the information on the server side from the global `$_POST` variable.

Comment: Why not? Your only client side alternative is to use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` then, but they will be more work as you need to ensure that the values came from the previous page only. Failing that you'll have to do something server-side.

Comment: *"give me the codes of php "* ... you could have easily researched this first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change your Main.html to Main.php
2. To get data in the Main.php with `post` method is just: `$_POST['q']`.

If you want to display your input text, just echo it: `echo $_POST['q']`.

Or you can save it into a variable too: `$var = $_POST['q']`.

---

Or if you don't want to use PHP, you can save input's value into a cookie and get that cookie's value in the Main.html with just JavaScript.

```
// function to get cookie || Parameter is your required cookie's name
function getcookie(cookiename)
{
    var name = cookiename+"=";
    var cookiearray = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<cookiearray.length; i++)
    {
        var c = cookiearray[i].trim();
        if(c.indexOf(name) === 0)
        {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. It was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have another option, if you don't want to use server side language...

you can use JavaScript, or it's library like jQuery to do that.

One HTML file:

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="q">
</form>
```

Other HTML file:

```
<div id="here"></div>
```

The jQuery file:

```
var result = $("input[name=q]").val();
$("#here").text(result);
```

if you want to use it, read more about JavaScript and jQuery... (Google)